# Getting the bound type of templated column controls in gridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, reflection, bind

Hi I have following grid view

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdSettings" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="100%"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="XYZ"  BoundFieldName="XYZTypeName">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CustomerName") %>'>
                                    </asp:Label>

                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCostumerId" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("CustomerId") %>'></asp:Label>

                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                     </asp:GridView>
```

Which is bound by List of Customer  ,class is as follows

```
Class Customer
{
  public string CustomerName { get; set; }
  public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

Now on a method named GetGridStuff() , i need to iterate in every column and get the type that was bound to controls in template field. For example in case of the first control in the template field

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CustomerName") %>' >
                                    </asp:Label>
```

I need to know what type of property data it contains , in this case its CustomerName. I need to get this dynamically at run time as to write code in part of program which is not aware if this grid structure. I have the grid object with me and i can access all properties.

Comment: If its not possible , then also please comment. Thanks

Comment: No inputs guys, need help !

Answer (score 1):

Let me try this, being away from coding for more than 5 years now and if I understand the problem correctly as you may want to handle it through server side code.

Look for an event called `ItemBound` (or similar forgive me for my memory), this gives you values of all the items in current row (Properties). You also need to declare temp control types (label,textbox etc) and assign corresponding value to these controls using `e.FindControl` with appropriate type casting, e.g. `Label l = (Label)e.Findcontrol("Name")`

downside of the approach you should avoid too much of process as it is going to execute on every row creating of the grid.

Let me know if you still want a precise code to handle the problem but otherwise this description should at least help you to look for Row Level Event to crack the prob and also encourage you to stick to tech forums :)

Comment: Getting bound types in the event is possible but getting the data type that was bound to a template field and the name of the property that was bound to that template field is my problem. I can extend and  introduce properties to the template field control to store this information to retrive them later, but was thinking of making  use of something existing.